# Use multiple file pointers for a single file in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, file, file-io, file-pointer

I am making a function that reads file data through multiple threads. Each thread reads different blocks of file, so that whole file reading operation is carried out by multiple threads. But I have no idea how to have a different file pointer for each thread.

What I am trying to do is that each thread reads a specific file area, so that multiple threads can read whole file in no time.

Any suggestions are appreciated, and please tell me if there are any logic flaws.

code till now

```
void fstreamExtension::readBytesMultiThreaded (std::vector<char>& vBuff)
{
long long int threadBytes [4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
//these if else statements calculate how many bytes each thread should read, basically file size in bytes is calculated from fileSize() and divided among threads.
if(this -> fileSize() % 2 == 0)
{
    threadBytes[0] = this -> fileSize() / 2;

    if(threadBytes[0] % 2 == 0)
    {
        threadBytes[0] /= 2;
        threadBytes[1] = threadBytes[0];
        threadBytes[2] = threadBytes[0];
        threadBytes[3] = threadBytes[0];
    }

    else
    {
        threadBytes[0] = (threadBytes[0] - 1) / 2;
        threadBytes[1] = threadBytes[0] + 1;
        threadBytes[2] = threadBytes[0];
        threadBytes[3] = threadBytes[1];
    }

}

else
{
    threadBytes[0] = (this -> fileSize() - 1) / 2;

    if(threadBytes[0] % 2 == 0)
    {
        threadBytes[0] /= 2;
        threadBytes[1] = threadBytes[0];
        threadBytes[2] = threadBytes[0];
        threadBytes[3] = threadBytes[0] + 1;
    }

    else
    {
        threadBytes[0] = (threadBytes[0] - 1) / 2;
        threadBytes[1] = threadBytes[0] + 1;
        threadBytes[2] = threadBytes[0] + 1;
        threadBytes[3] = threadBytes[0] + 1;
    }
 }
}
```

data read by threads will be combined into a single vector type buffer accepted as arguement of fuunction.

say I have 4 lines in a file.

-line 1

-line 2

-line 3

-line 4

what I want is to create four threads, thread1 will read line1,thread2 will read line2, thread3 will read line3, thread4 will read line4. Note that I'll be using only 4 threads.

What I am asking is for each thread I may need to place file pointer at start of the line that thread has to read. For 4 threads to read file concurrently four file pointers may be needed. So, I want to know how to have multiple file pointers for a single file.

You may relate each line to a file block, the reading process remains same.

Please suggest if there are other solution available for this besides multiple file pointers.

thanks!

Comment: can you please explain your example more..its not clear yet..

Comment: just open a separate file handle for each thread?

Comment: @setia_, check I've edited the post and added some more explantion for the problem

Comment: Using more threads will not make the hard disk any faster. Disk read is hardly ever limited by CPU speed.

Comment: @AlanBirtles, actually I thought of it too, but for large files it would be incurring significant overhead, so I am kinda avoiding this solution right now.

Comment: I don't understand 'incurring significant overhead' issue with each thread opening the fiel for read but, OK, lets assume that you have tested that, (?).  Open the file in one thread, read the buffers, queue the buffers off to the other threads.

Comment: Note @BoPersson point.  You will gain if your design starts to process the data that was read earlier, (because you only have to read 1/4 of the file before data processing starts), or if the data processing takes so much CPU that it dominates the overall operation, (so that each 1/4 is processed by a different thread).  It's not clear how your full app works, so that is difficult to judge from here:)

Comment: @MartinJames, I am implementing a class that inherits from fstream, moreover file will be opened just once, and I am trying that the file_read() function will launch 4 threads to read the file. Which I think is different from opening the same file through 4 different objects. And as for BoPersson's point I have to read data through 4 threads, that means it isn't already read. Also, for application, it is a file encryption utility that encrypt text, image and video files. I am doing this because reading video files takes significant time, I tested it on a 95MB video and utility took around 14s

Comment: So can I conclude that all of you are suggesting that reading file from the disk won't get faster with multiple threads and it can't be implemented?

Comment: @Nilesh you can do it, but it does not sound optimal.  Serial reading of the file into four buffers, then processing the buffers in four threads, sounds like a much better bet.  The file then only needs to be read seqiuentially once, the encryption can begin as soon as the first 1/4 has been read.  Also, I have to ask, how small a chunk will allow the overall encryption mechanism to work?  If you say, split up the whole file into 8K blocks, encrypted each block separately and then concatenated the encrypted outputs, would that result in a valid encrypted file?

Comment: In the end, the best way to find out is to try it.  Calculating how many bytes for each thread would seem to be easy?  Divide by 4, that gives the byte count for 3 out of 4 threads,  Multiply up by 4 and subtract from filesize gives the count for the last thread.

Comment: @MartinJames, thanks for your suggestion, it definitely seems better than my approach. For encryption, I am implementing AES algorithm that specifies 128bit block size for encryption, since file is read byte by byte and not through formatted input functions, so it seems viable to concatenate encrypted chunks in a file and decrypt it back when needed. Also I have checked this, I wrote a code that reads a file byte by byte and write it to another file, unless file extension is changed a perfect copy of file is created, may it be a text, image or vdeo file, I have tested it for all three.